# Getting error when loading ggplot2 in my R session in RStudio

Tags: r

I am getting below error while loading ggplot2 package in my R session. initially i got some other error while loading ggplot2 which i resolved when i reinstalled some dependent packages but i am not able to resolve this one.

Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘colorspace’
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘ggplot2’ was built under R version 3.2.5 
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’

i have tried removing ggplot2 and reinstalling it, and it didn't work. i have also updated all packages. i would really appreciate any help resolving this.
i am using base R version 3.2.3 and RStudio Version 1.0.136  and win10

Comment: have you installed the `colorspace` package?  What happens if you try `library(colorspace)` ?

Comment: I tried it before it didn't work, but then i manually copied colorspace folder from CRAN site and copied in R folder in my documents. It is working now.